# How can I use Gaussian elimination for finding QNMs in this code?

Tags: list-manipulation, physics

I am reading the article *[Scalar-gravitational perturbations and quasinormal modes in the five dimensional Schwarzschild black hole](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0311260)*. I want to reproduce the value of the quasinormal frequency with $l=2, n=0$ in Table 1 of that article by using the continued fractions method, which is extended in the article by [E. W. Leaver (1985)](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1985.0119).

However, the situation in the first article is more complicated, because there are 8-term recurrence relations. In order to use the continued fractions method, we need reducing the 8-term recurrence relation to 3-term recurrence relation with the aid of Gaussian elimination, which is explained in [V. Cardoso et al. (2003)](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0309112).

The following code can realize Gaussian elimination thanks to A. Zhidenko.

```
NewL=FoldList[If[PossibleZeroQ[#2//Last],#2//Most,
Most[#2]-(#2//Last)/(#1//Last)*Prepend[#1//Most,0]]&,L//First//Most,L//Rest];
```

Then I attempt to use this command reproducing the results in the first article. However, I met some problems in this work. I don't know how to solve these puzzles. Could you help me making it work?

The complete code is as follows,

```
LEAVER[ω_, l_, NITMAX_] := (
        rh = 1;
   z1 = 1/rh;
   m = l (l + 2) - 3;
   ρ = I ω/2/z1;
   (*********************)
   c[0] = Function[k, 2 (1 + k) (6 + m)^2 (1 + k + 2 ρ)];
   c[1] = 
    Function[
     k, -(6 + m) (m^2 + (78 + 5 m) k^2 + 
        10 m (1 + 2 ρ) ρ + (30 + 5 m + 216 ρ + 
           20 m ρ) k + 12 (1 + 5 ρ + 10 ρ^2))];
   c[2] = 
    Function[k, 
     1/2 (8 (324 + 48 m + m^2) k^2 + m^2 (1 + 32 ρ^2) + 
        12 m (13 - 48 ρ + 112 ρ^2) + 
        36 (41 - 128 ρ + 192 ρ^2) + 
        16 k (-198 + 540 ρ + 2 m^2 ρ + 
           3 m (-7 + 30 ρ)))];
   c[3] = 
    Function[k, 
     1/4 (-4 (1980 + 168 m + m^2) (-2 + k)^2 - m^2 (3 + 4 ρ)^2 - 
        12 m (69 + 192 ρ + 224 ρ^2) - 
        36 (129 + 520 ρ + 752 ρ^2) - 
        4 (-2 + k) (m^2 (3 + 4 ρ) + 96 m (3 + 7 ρ) + 
           36 (65 + 204 ρ)))];
   c[4] = 
    Function[k, 
     12 (6 (25 + m) k^2 + m (25 - 44 ρ + 24 ρ^2) + 
        6 (127 - 214 ρ + 96 ρ^2) + (-660 + 588 ρ + 
           m (-22 + 24 ρ)) k)];
   c[5] = 
    Function[
     k, -3 (4 (81 + m) k^2 + m (29 - 40 ρ + 16 ρ^2) + 
        6 (491 - 644 ρ + 216 ρ^2) + 
        4 (-483 + 324 ρ + m (-5 + 4 ρ)) k)];
   c[6] = 
    Function[k, 
     18 (227 + 16 k^2 - 240 ρ + 64 ρ^2 + 
        8 (-15 + 8 ρ) k)];
   c[7] = Function[k, -9 (-9 + 2 k + 4 ρ)^2];
   (************)
   α[2, 
     1] = α[3, 
      1] = α[4, 
       1] = α[5, 1] = α[6, 1] = α[7, 1] = 0;
   α[3, 
     2] = α[4, 
      2] = α[5, 2] = α[6, 2] = α[7, 2] = 0;
   α[4, 
     3] = α[5, 3] = α[6, 3] = α[7, 3] = 0;
   α[5, 4] = α[6, 4] = α[7, 4] = 0;
   α[6, 5] = α[7, 5] = 0;
   α[7, 6] = 0;
   (***************)
   α[j_, i_] := c[j][i - 1];
   fs = Table[α[j, i], {i, 1, NITMAX}, {j, 0, 7}];
   Do[Nfs = 
       FoldList[
        If[PossibleZeroQ[#2 // Last], #2 // 
           Most, (Most[#2] - (#2 // Last)/(#1 // Last)*
              Prepend[#1 // Most, 0]) // Together] &, 
        fs // First // Most, fs // Rest]; fs = Nfs, 5]
     (*αtl=Function[n,Nfs[[n+1,1]]];
            βtl=Function[n,Nfs[[n+1,2]]];
            γtl=Function[n,Nfs[[n+1,3]]];*)
     rl = Nfs;
        Leaver31 = Module[{Rn},
     For[{n = NITMAX - 1; Rn = -1.0;},
      n > -1,
      {
       Rn = rl[[n + 1, 3]]/(rl[[n + 1, 2]] - rl[[n + 1, 1]]*Rn); n--;}
      ]; Rn];
         Leaver33 = rl[[1, 2]]/rl[[1, 1]] - Leaver31);
```

```
fun[x_?NumberQ] := LEAVER[x, 2, 102]
```

```
winit = 0.9 + 0.2 I;
```

```
In[4]:= FindRoot[fun[x] == 0, {x, winit}]

During evaluation of In[4]:= Set::write: Tag Times in Null rl is Protected.

During evaluation of In[4]:= Part::partd: Part specification rl[[102,3]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[4]:= Part::partd: Part specification rl[[102,2]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[4]:= Part::partd: Part specification rl[[102,1]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[4]:= General::stop: Further output of Part::partd will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[4]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {rl[[1,2]]/rl[[1,1]]-(1. rl[[1,3]])/(rl[[1,2]]-(1. rl[[1,1]] rl[[2,3]])/Plus[<<2>>])} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {0.9 +0.2 I}.

Out[4]= FindRoot[fun[x] == 0, {x, winit}]
```

Comment: It would be good to isolate this better, or at least to construct a smaller example. The error messages should also help to see that some code is expecting longer objects than it actually has,